# How to remove duplicate attributes from HTML without using HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, tags

I have html like

```
    ...<button type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl16$ctl00$ctl00$searchButton" value=""
 id="ctl00_ctl16_ctl00_ctl00_searchButton" type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">...
```

and need programicaly remove duplicate tags, like type="submit" from it. Is it possible with out using libriaries like HTMLAgilityPack? Regexp, for example.

Comment: Is it possible? Well, C# is Turing complete, so sure. RegExp, on its own, no. What's wrong with HTMLAgilityPack?

Comment: I can't use any lib on that task. That part of task HTMLParser which is for challenge.

Comment: But can't you just modify the original ASPX? I mean, this is obviously ASP.NET, so I see no reason why you should go and correct the generated HTML. Next time it's generated, you'll have the duplicated attributes again.

Comment: this is part of html from http://www.microsoft.com/ru-by/default.aspx which i am trying to parse. The whole task is take all css files from html, and search unsued styles on that page with out using libs. And my solution is - make from css selectors xpathes, and use Xdocument. But method Xdocument.Parse fails on any invalid html, so i do pre-parse cleanning :)

Comment: I think i found solution. But not the best. I use XDocument.Parse, and get @"'(.*)' is a duplicate attribute name. Line (\d), position (\d*)."; exception, then i parse it with regex and replace attribute with it's value from html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to remove duplicate attributes *within the same tag*, then this is tricky because you can't do it without parsing out each tag. And parsing out each tag requires parsing everything else, including comments, text, quoted text, etc.

So the only way you can do this without using a library is to basically write your own HTML parser. That's why it would be easier to use HTML Agility Pack or my own [HTML Monkey](https://github.com/SoftCircuits/HtmlMonkey).